# How to get rid of ssh connection between server with multiple clients?

Tags: java, file-upload, ssh, client-server, sftp

I friends I need guidance to change the architecture between main sever and clients?
Every day the nain server needs to place request file at mutiple clients server, in current world we establish the ssh connection between main server and multiple clients.. some time the ssh connection getting loss and not able to send the file properly.. so we want to remove ssh logic and want to come up with new architecture with java/j2ee.. so please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Why not start to use a pull mechanism instead of a push mechanism; e.g. the clients will ask the server for the required file. That way the number of clients and kind of clients also becomes independent from the server; meaning that you can add and remove clients without having to modify the server. 
The clients should retry at regular basis when file is not available or transport of file failed (all that logic is within the client).